# How can I show data one after another in django models

Tags: python, django

I am Using Django Framework in my project. I want the results that start with query first then results that contain query next but when I am using the following code it is giving mixed results instead of one after other. How can I achieve My requirement

```
collections = TokenCollection.objects.filter(Q(title__istartswith=query) | Q(title__icontains=query))
```

Comment: When asking for records from a data repository, the order is usually undefined unless you specify it yourself. You can do that by sorting using the django QuerySet API, or by getting 2 lists back and joining them in python code. Both will work, but the database is optimised for large select/sort operations so is usually the preferred choice.

Answer (score 0):

Something using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) might suit your needs, but you might run into performance problems if the returned dataset is large:

```
from itertools import chain

collections = list(chain(
    TokenCollection.objects.filter(title__istartswith=query),
    TokenCollection.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
                           .exclu‌​de(title__istartswit‌​h=query)
))
```

Comment: it give doubles in the result

Comment: That might be true, but you did not specify your requirement that duplicates should be removed. There are different ways this can be done, the 'right' one will depend on what you want.

Comment: not maybe  it is always true, look on the condition the same field

Comment: You can simply exclude the condition of the first queryset like this: `TokenCollection.objects.filter(title__icontains=query).exclude(title__istartswith=query)`

Comment: i am not OP, i just try to help you

Comment: I see, and you are right of course. I interpreted the question as 'how to chain querysets', while the question is more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from django.db.models import Q, Case, Value, IntegerField


TokenCollection.objects.filter(
    Q(title__istartswith=query) | Q(title__icontains=query)
).annotate(
    c=Case(
        When(title__istartswith=query, then=Value(1)),
        When(title__icontains=query, then=Value(2)),
        output_field=IntegerField())
).order_by('c')
```